# Opening a batch file (.bat) in a C program?

Tags: c, gcc, batch-file

How do I start running a batch file (.bat) from my C program? I used

```
system("start /B omanam.bat");
```

but it's not working. How can I make .bat to open through C?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drop the `start`. It's a cmd.exe thing. Just run `system("omanam.bat");`.

Comment: @niko, bad command? Don't know why this would happen, but you can also try `"cmd /c omanam.bat"`, which will have cmd.exe run the batch. Also, are you sure omanam.bat is in the current directory? What happens if you use a full path?

Comment: yes it is in current directory in the gcc compiler it says omnama.bat command not found and in the turbo c it open the command prompt but its not executing any command just disaply bad commands and exiting out

Comment: @niko, but what happens if you use a full path? Try monitoring the program's run using [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645), and see where it is looking for that batch file. Sounds like it can't find it, and knowing where it was looking could be helpful.

Comment: @niko, also, at your response you say "omnama.bat command not found", but the batch you try to run, according to your code, is named omanam.bat. Is this a typo here or on the program?

Comment: Yes eran it started working after using the full path and i made it like these system("./omanam,bat"); it started working and Thank you for spending your time with me

Answer (score 2):

If your C executable program and batch file are in same directory then

```
system("batchfilename.bat arg1 arg2");
```

where `arg1` and `arg2` are the arguments for this batch file.

---

If the batch file is in another directory

```
 system("f:\\bin\\batchfilename.bat arg1 arg2");
```

where `arg1` and `arg2` are the arguments for this batch file.

---

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

  printf("Calling batch file doit.bat\n");
  system("doit Hello. theansweris: 42");
  printf("Press \'Enter\' to exit the program\n");
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Batch file code:

```
@rem This is the batch file doit.bat
@echo.
@echo.
@echo.
@echo In doit.bat:
@echo.
@echo.
@echo.
@echo argument #1 is ^"%1^"
@echo argument #2 is ^"%2^"
@echo argument #3 is ^"%3^"
@echo.
@echo.
@echo Tttttthat's all, folks!
@echo.
@echo.
```